# Email: text preview on mobile client and browser

Tags: html, email, preview

guys
I'm trying to create e good html code for my newsletter. I've checked a lot of best practice but I cannot find the right tips for me.

You know: email client on mobile show the first two or three lines in the code... and due the first line is always "If you can't read this email, please click on..." etc.

I'd like to know is there's a tag or a way to choose another text to show up on the email preview when received by my customers. (of course, without changing the first line referring to the web version of the email)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a preheader. You would simply put that content before your 'webversion' link in your html email.

Here are some related articles:

- [Campaign Monitor: A practical guide to preheaders](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3628/a-practical-guide-to-email-preheaders/)
- [Better preheaders? Six ideas to consider...](http://www.email-marketing-reports.com/iland/2008/01/better-preheaders-six-ideas-to-consider.html)

Comment: So, it's just a simple text line? But in your exemples i can see that a style tag is used to hide that line... I thougt it wasn't a good idea to write a style tag on newsletter, but maybe I'm wrong...
BTW: thanks a lot!

Comment: Campaign Monitor utilizes a technique to hide it in the body, so that it is only seen in the email preview. You don’t need to do this if you are happy to include it in small text at the top of your email. Style tags are not supported by all email clients, but they are still useful for addressing other clients like Outlook, that have various ‘quirks’ of their own. Also all media queries are in the style tag, which makes them only partially supported...

Comment: ...In email it is a game of percentages (which email clients are your subscribers using) and graceful degradation (making it still look good if they are using a client that allows less bells and whistles).